# Housing the DAO layer inside a Scala Akka Actor

Tags: scala, persistence, akka

I am getting warmed up to Scala but am still very new to Akka. This seems like a fairly straightforward question, but I was not able to find any information on this specific approach, which tells me that something might be wrong with my thinking or that there is already a very standard way to do this.

All of the solutions I found revolve around having an Akka actor make calls to a pre-built service layer, which would handle the database logic.

My question is whether it is feasible to make the DAO itself a persistent actor. Something along the lines of this:

```scala
class UserDAO extends Actor {
    val db = actorSystem.actorSelection("/repository/dao")

    def receive = {
        case GetUserById(id) => sender ! (db ? RunStoredProc(SpGetUserById(id)))
        ...
    }
}
```

The above is purely hypothetical pseudo-code and all the methods (i.e. `RunStoredProc`) are intended as examples only. I am more curious about the sanity behind the design decision of such a system. The `UserDAO` and the `DAO`(`db`) actors would be persistent and stateless (albeit `DAO` would hold a handle to the database connection). What I mean by persistent is that they would not be instantiated by the actors that actually call them.

Am I re-inventing the wheel here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach seems perfectly feasible. This would allow you to handle all connection based logic in one place.

The one caveat to consider is that if your DAO is synchronous, using a single actor for all DOA calls would mean only one DB call can execute at one time. This may or may not be desirable.